Display value on line chart Prime NG Angular 16

I want to show the value on chart like that

i am using Angular 16 and for chart prime Ng
Please help me
I   am trying to display value on chart not showing. tool tip is  showing but value is not showing on the graph. cloud you please help me.

Primeng charts use Chart.js as the library, with chart.js showing datalabels on the charts can be done using chartjs-plugin-datalabels
First install chartjs-plugin-datalabels
npm i chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Then you need to add the plugin using
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

After this, we need to create a plugin array which will contain the newly installed library
plugin = [ChartDataLabels];

Then we add the configuration needed for showing the label at the correct position
....
this.basicOptions = {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      anchor: 'end',
      align: 'end',
    },
    ...

Full code
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

@Component({
  selector: 'chart-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './chart-basic-demo.html',
})
export class ChartBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  basicData: any;
  plugin = [ChartDataLabels];

  basicOptions: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const documentStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
    const textColor = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--text-color');
    const textColorSecondary = documentStyle.getPropertyValue(
      '--text-color-secondary'
    );
    const surfaceBorder = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--surface-border');

    this.basicData = {
      labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Sales',
          data: [540, 325, 702, 620],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
            'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      ],
    };

    this.basicOptions = {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
        },
        legend: {
          labels: {
            color: textColor,
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          ticks: {
            color: textColorSecondary,
          },
          grid: {
            color: surfaceBorder,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
        x: {
          ticks: {
            color: textColorSecondary,
          },
          grid: {
            color: surfaceBorder,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
